# Listing available COM Objects with Powershell

Tags: powershell, com-object

I am currently using the following script to list the available COM Objects on my machine.

```
$path = "REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\*\PROGID"
foreach ($obj in dir $path) {
    write-host $obj.GetValue("")
}
```

I read on another website that the existence of the InProcServer32 key is evidence that the object is 64 bit compatible.

So using powershell how can I determine the existence of InProcServer32 for each COM Object? If that is even the correct way of establishing whether it is 32 bit or 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether that is the way to determine 64-bit compatibility but the way to see if a regkey exists is to use Test-Path e.g.:

```
PS> Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE
True
PS> Test-Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE2
False
```

In your case:

```
$path = "REGISTRY::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\*\PROGID" 
foreach ($obj in dir $path) { 
    write-host $obj.GetValue("") 
    if (Test-Path (Join-Path $obj.PSParentPath 'InprocServer32'))
    {
        # key exists
    }
}
```